# Interpretting benchmarks of preallocating a slice

Tags: go, slice

I've been trying to understand slice preallocation with `make`  and *why* it's a good idea. I noticed a large performance difference between preallocating a slice and appending to it vs just initializing it with 0 length/capacity and then appending to it. I wrote a set of very simple benchmarks:

```
import "testing"

func BenchmarkNoPreallocate(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Don't preallocate our initial slice
        init := []int64{}
        init = append(init, 5)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPreallocate(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Preallocate our initial slice
        init := make([]int64, 0, 1)
        init = append(init, 5)
    }
}
```

and was a little puzzled with the results:

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkNoPreallocate-4    30000000            41.8 ns/op         8 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkPreallocate-4      2000000000           0.29 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

I have a couple of questions:

- Why are there no allocations (it shows 0 allocs/op) in the preallocation benchmark case? Certainly we're preallocating, but the allocation *had* to have happened at some point.
- I imagine this may become clearer after the first question is answered, but how is the preallocation case so much quicker? Am I misinterpetting this benchmark?

Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go has an optimizing compiler. Constants are evaluated at compile time. Variables are evaluated at runtime. Constant values can be used to optimize compiler generated code. For example,

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkNoPreallocate(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Don't preallocate our initial slice
        init := []int64{}
        init = append(init, 5)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPreallocateConst(b *testing.B) {
    const (
        l = 0
        c = 1
    )
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Preallocate our initial slice
        init := make([]int64, l, c)
        init = append(init, 5)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPreallocateVar(b *testing.B) {
    var (
        l = 0
        c = 1
    )
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Preallocate our initial slice
        init := make([]int64, l, c)
        init = append(init, 5)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test alloc_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkNoPreallocate-4         50000000    39.3 ns/op     8 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkPreallocateConst-4    2000000000     0.36 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkPreallocateVar-4        50000000    28.2 ns/op     8 B/op    1 allocs/op
```

---

Another interesting set of benchmarks:

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkNoPreallocate(b *testing.B) {
    const (
        l = 0
        c = 8 * 1024
    )
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Don't preallocate our initial slice
        init := []int64{}
        for j := 0; j < c; j++ {
            init = append(init, 42)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkPreallocateConst(b *testing.B) {
    const (
        l = 0
        c = 8 * 1024
    )
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Preallocate our initial slice
        init := make([]int64, l, c)
        for j := 0; j < cap(init); j++ {
            init = append(init, 42)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkPreallocateVar(b *testing.B) {
    var (
        l = 0
        c = 8 * 1024
    )
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Preallocate our initial slice
        init := make([]int64, l, c)
        for j := 0; j < cap(init); j++ {
            init = append(init, 42)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test peter_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkNoPreallocate-4       20000   75656 ns/op   287992 B/op   19 allocs/op
BenchmarkPreallocateConst-4   100000   22386 ns/op    65536 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkPreallocateVar-4     100000   22112 ns/op    65536 B/op    1 allocs/op
```

Comment: So in the `BenchmarkNoPreallocate` vs `BenchmarkPreallocateVar` case, what makes the preallocation case ~10ns quicker? Isn't the append in the `BenchmarkNoPreallocate` case going to allocate the underlying array to have a capacity of 1 in a similar way?

Comment: @AlexanderKohler: `BenchmarkPreallocateVar` knows exactly how much slice capacity (and length) it needs to allocate. `BenchmarkNoPreallocate` leaves it up to `append` to discover that it needs to grow the slice length (and capacity) from  0 to 1. It takes time to do that. See `growslice` (`go/src/runtime/slice.go`) which handles slice growth during `append`.